# How do move the content under the image?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to use flex and order to show the images first and the content. Right now, how do I push or move the content under the image? I don't want them next to each other. I don't want to remove the flex because if I remove it the order is not working. That means the image won't show first. This code is for my mobile version, but I'm testing it for desktop right now.

```css
img {
    width: 100%;
}
.music-wrapper {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: flex;
}
.poster-content {
    -webkit-order: 2;            
    order: 2; 
}
.poster-wrap {
    -webkit-order: 1;            
    order: 1; 
}
```

```html
<section class="row-wrap">
    <div class="row-inner music-wrapper">
        <div class="poster-wrap">
            <img class="poster" src="http://dummyimage.com/420x420/000/fff"> 
        </div>
        <div class="poster-content">
            <h1>Sunday</h1>
            <p>Carefully selected songs to get you in a mellow state of mind after a week of hard work. A perfect mixtape to get ready to chase your dream again on Monday.</p>
            <a class="btn-wrap" target="_blank" href="#">
                <div class="btn">listen now</div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="row-wrap">
    <div class="row-inner music-wrapper">
        <div class="poster-content">
            <h1>Sunday</h1>
            <p>Carefully selected songs to get you in a mellow state of mind after a week of hard work. A perfect mixtape to get ready to chase your dream again on Monday.</p>
            <a class="btn-wrap" target="_blank" href="#">
                <div class="btn">listen now</div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="poster-wrap">
            <img class="poster" src="http://dummyimage.com/420x420/000/fff"> 
        </div> 
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `flex-direction:column;` to `.music-wrapper`. See this solution:

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
}
.music-wrapper {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
} 
.poster-content {
  -webkit-order: 2;            
  order: 2; 
}
.poster-wrap {
  -webkit-order: 1;            
  order: 1; 
}
```

```html
<section class="row-wrap">
  <div class="row-inner music-wrapper">
    <div class="poster-wrap">
      <img class="poster" src="http://dummyimage.com/420x420/000/fff"> 
    </div>
    <div class="poster-content">
      <h1>Sunday</h1>
      <p>Carefully selected songs to get you in a mellow state of mind after a week of hard work. A perfect mixtape to get ready to chase your dream again on Monday.</p>
      <a class="btn-wrap" target="_blank" href="#">
        <div class="btn">listen now</div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="row-wrap">
  <div class="row-inner music-wrapper">
    <div class="poster-content">
      <h1>Sunday</h1>
      <p>Carefully selected songs to get you in a mellow state of mind after a week of hard work. A perfect mixtape to get ready to chase your dream again on Monday.</p>
      <a class="btn-wrap" target="_blank" href="#">
        <div class="btn">listen now</div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="poster-wrap">
      <img class="poster" src="http://dummyimage.com/420x420/000/fff"> 
    </div> 
  </div>
</section>
```

Additionaly you can use the shorthand `flex-flow:column;`. But it is not needed because the `flex-direction` does the work. A explanation of the `flex-flow`:

> This is a shorthand flex-direction and flex-wrap properties, which together define the flex container's main and cross axes. Default is `row nowrap`.
>   https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/